# Dealing with a high volume of query params in python

Tags: python, design-patterns

We have an api that consumes a around 50 to 100 query params. Currently the handler takes all of the params and sets them as attributes in a Meta object. Something like this

```
meta = Meta()
meta.param1 = param.get('param1', 'somedefault')
meta.param2 = param.get('param2', 'someotherdefault')
```

and so on. My question is, is there a better way to handle this than just a loooong list of assigns in the handler? My current idea is to just break it out into a helper function.

```
meta = self.get_meta(param)
```

Any other ideas?

(updated my example)

Comment: I would suggest using a context object that you pass around.

Comment: @Keith Similar to what we're doing now?

Comment: Oh, i see. Well, considering that you have hard-coded default values that is probably the most clear and maintainable approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PARAMETERS = [
    'param1',
    'param2',
    # ...
]

meta = Meta()
for name in PARAMETERS:
    setattr(meta, name, param[name])
```

Based on your comment...

```
DEFAULTS = {
    'param1': 1,
    'param2': 'something',
}
meta = Meta()
for name, value in DEFAULTS.items():
    setattr(meta, name, param.get(name, value))
```

Comment: While I would love the simplicity, we often must assign defaults if the value is not present (some are optional but still need a value).

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something you should do with a mapping instead. Unless you need to filter the parameters, this sounds like a bad idea.

So you'll have something like this:

```
class Meta(IterableUserDict):
    pass

meta = Meta()
meta.update(param)
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on whats been said including default values

```
PARAMETERS = [
    ('param1', "default"),
    ('param2', "default2"),
    # ...
]

meta = Meta()
for name, default in PARAMETERS:
    setattr(meta, name, param.get(name, default))
```